# difference between mediacodec PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE and KEY_BIT_RATE

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am trying to encode using MediaCodec in surface-input mode and to set the required bitrate, but I dont understand if I should use PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE in mediacodec or KEY_BIT_RATE in the MediaFormat. What is the usage of each parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you configure codec you have to use KEY_BIT_RATE to set encoding bitrate. In API 19 PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE was added to change encoding bitrate after processing started - it could be used for streaming for example - if network conditions change you may want to adjust bitrate without other encoding parameters reconfigure

Comment: Is there any callback if the bitrate has been adjusted ?